# Cable tray width selection as per NEC 392

Tags: design, cables, electrical, calculation

I would like to ask if anyone know what is the meaning of the letter b used in the formula in the table 392.22 National electrical code 2017 article 392, pic (attached)
[image]

Comment: It means that there is a footnote labeled (b) and that footnote applies to those data values.

Comment: Do you mean that b is not a part of the equation?

Thanks alot for your reply

Comment: That's right...it's not a mathematical symbol. Look at the heading labeled Column2\$^a\$...there is a footnote (a) somewhere that applies to the whole column.